# Need sed command to replace JSON property value

Tags: json, bash, sed

I have a JSON file as mentioned below

```
{"channel1":{"number":"xxxxxxxxx","recording_id":"hsdsghgsdhfsgjsjdfjsdjjsdgjgsjghjsdfsdj"},"channel2":{"number":"xxxxxxx","status":"ANSWER"}}
```

I need to replace the `recording_id` property as empty

I mean I need the final out put as

```
{"channel1":{"number":"xxxxxxxxx","recording_id":""},"channel2":{"number":"xxxxxxx","status":"ANSWER"}}
```

I have tried the below mentioned solution

```sh
sed -i 's/\"recording_id\":.*/\"recording_id\": '""'/g' filename
```

Got the output as

```
{"channel1":{"number":"xxxxxxxxx","recording_id":
```

which is not what I want. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the `.*` in your pattern matches everything to the end of the string, but you want to replace only the value of the `recording_id` attribute.

It would be better to use a tool that understands JSON, but if you have to do it with `sed` then you could modify your command like so:

```
sed -i 's/"recording_id":"[^"]*/"recording_id":"/g' filename
```

The pattern fragment `[^"]*` matches a maximal run of zero or more  characters *other than `"`*.

Note also that, as shown, you do not need to escape the double-quotes inside your single-quoted string.  In fact, in the original, that quoting is processed not by the shell, but by `sed`, yet quotation marks have no special significance to `sed` in the first place.

Comment: As the single quotes get processed by the shell, the empty quotes `""` which are actually *outside* the single quotes will get removed, too.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused about the quoting, and about the regex.

First off, `.*` will match the entire remainder of the input line; you (are trying to) replace all that with `""`, so that explains why your output appears truncated.

Secondly, inside single quotes, you can simply use double quotes verbatim.

Now, the regex to match only the `"recording_id":` field would be something like `"[^"]*"` which says to match up to the next double quote, then as many characters which are not double quotes as we can find, then another double quote.

```sh
sed -i 's/"recording_id": *"[^"]*"/"recording_id": ""/' filename
```

Unless you *expect* more than one match per input line, the `/g` flag is useless here.

But as ever, the proper solution is to use a JSON-capable tool like `jq` instead.  `sed` is notoriously poor for this, as a (reasonably straightforward) regular expression cannot distinguish `"recording_id"` at the top-level JSON from the same string as e.g. the value in a dictionary somewhere else in the structure.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your solution. It worked. But it is not replacing the same for second occurrence.

Comment: Your example only has one instance. Like it says, add the `g` flag back if you expect multiple matches per line.

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't** have to use `sed`, then you might use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) like so

```sh
jq '.channel1.recording_id = ""' your_file.json > new_file.json
```